# Why push method works on with object?

Tags: javascript

Why does "push method" works with object? How that mechanism works underhood?

```
function MyArray() { }
MyArray.prototype = [];

var arr = new MyArray();
arr.push(1, 2, 3);
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3]  in Chrome
```

[image]

sorry for my english. Thanks!

Comment: arrays are object too

Comment: You're assign the prototype to an array, then pushing to that array...?

Comment: `MyArray` *is* an array, since you explicitly said you want it to be one via the `prototype`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan could you please write a real answer for this.

Comment: MyArray is not array

Comment: @Soviut I'm planning on voting to close the question, since it's likely a duplicate, so no, I will not write a real answer for this question. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: But of course Nina comes along and answers all of the questions I'm going to mark as duplicate...

Comment: @Jim Button it is (mostly) ! youve defined  that (MyArray.prototype=[])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: @Jonasw No `({}).toString.call(arr) //"[object Object]", Array.isArray(arr) //false`

Comment: [] is an Object with a prototype={ push:...} if you do MyArray.prototype=[], push is inside of MyArrays prototype chain... it may not be an array in javascript but it behaves like that trough the prototyping

Comment: for example, "concat method" is not working: jsfiddle.net/f8r6j24p

Comment: why not use an array?

Comment: @NinaScholz it is simple. But question is not about that :)

Answer (score 2):

`MyArray` returns an object, even in Chrome, and uses the methods of [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), via assigned [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). The result of an instance of `MyArray` is still an object, not an array.

```js
function MyArray() { }
MyArray.prototype = [];

var arr = new MyArray();
arr.push(1, 2, 3);
console.log(arr);                    // { 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, length: 3 }
console.log(typeof arr);             // object
console.log(Array.isArray(arr));     // false
console.log(arr instanceof Array);   // true
console.log(arr instanceof MyArray); // true
```

Comment: Thank you! But i think, that problem is more deeper

Comment: @JimButton, what do you mean by *deeper*?

Comment: for example, "concat method" not working: https://jsfiddle.net/f8r6j24p/